# Configure OpenTelemetry to fail when sending traces to an exporter fail

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, trace, open-telemetry

We require that data is highly correct, more so than 100% uptime (I recognize this may mean that opentelemetry is not the best choice but still would like to know if its possible).
We are exporting to elastic using APM.

I have noticed 2 significant issues.

Issue 1: I provide no/incorrect bearer token. No errors (or traces) are recorded. Silent failure.

Issue 2: I try to write a huge number of traces (100k) as fast as possible. About 2k make it and the rest are discarded.

```
        var tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
            .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())
            .AddSource("MyCompany.MyProduct.MyLibrary")
            .AddOtlpExporter(o =>
            {
                o.ExportProcessorType = ExportProcessorType.Batch;
                o.TimeoutMilliseconds = 100 * 1000;
                o.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.Grpc;
                o.Endpoint = new Uri("https://somepath:443");
                o.Headers = "Authorization=Bearer token1";
            })
            //.AddConsoleExporter()
            .Build();

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                using (var activity = MyActivitySource.StartActivity("SayHello"))
                {
                    activity?.SetTag("foo", 1);
                }
            }
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start [otel collector](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector) locally - then point your app code to local otel collector and local otel collector will export traces to Elastic APM.

Configure local otel collector:

1.) Enable telemetry metrics and monitor failed metrics of used OTLP exporter, e.g. https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/15983

2.) Use aggresive batching - [batch processor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/tree/main/processor/batchprocessor) before exporting to Elastic APM, e.g.

```
        processors:
          batch:
            send_batch_size: 10000
            timeout: 5s
            send_batch_max_size: 0
```

Collector will decrease ingestion rate to Elastic APM thank to batching. Of course you need to test it first, because some trace backend implementation uses defaults - e.g. GRPC for Go has default 4MB GRPC message size and 10k traces in one message will very likely exceeds this limit. Very often these infrastructure/app limits are not documented, so stress testing before production is highly recommended. Keep in mind that batching will require additional memory, so monitor also memory usage.

I would customize [retry and queue](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/exporter/exporterhelper/README.md) behaviour.

Comment: Retry is usefully, but definitely not a solution. What if the networking has gone down? Then retry will not help and the program would continue to execute. Batching is much the same, yes it increases the limit which is great. But a limit still exists and can be hit realistically. So unless I can make that trigger some sort of failure logic I still can't go in to my trace viewer (elastic) and say "yes I am sure that nothing happened that is not here in this database"

Comment: @ghostbust555 it is really not clear what are you trying to solve "100% uptime". If it is availability or maximization of ingestion rate then scale otel collectors horizontally as standard stateless app (loadbalancer with healthchecks and 2+ OTEL collector instances with autoscaling). Single collector instance (1CPU/2GB RAM) has max recomended rate 10k traces/sec - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/performance.md

Comment: My problem is simple. I cannot have missing logs under any scenario. See my question scenarios 1 and 2. Issue 1 is a perfect example. If I provide an incorrect bearer token (say there was a password rotation due to a security issue) there is no way to detect that every single log is failing. That is critically bad. Unusably bad in my case.

Comment: @ghostbust555 that is by design - receiver only receives (then processor my process) and only exporter at the end will know if export was succesfull or not = you need to monitor exporter failed metrics. You can configure persistent queue so failed ingestions from the exporter may be saved to the disk = you won't loose traces (you are refering them sometimes as logs, but logs != traces) - they just will be delivered later, when you fix an issue `If collector instance is killed while having some items in the persistent queue, on restart the items are being picked and the exporting is continued.`